# Ring Buffer with built-in microphone audio in python

Tags: python

I’m very new to python, but I’m looking for a way to continuously store the last two seconds of audio from a built-in microphone so it can be used in a callback function.

(Side note, I don’t actually know what a callback function is or does, but apparently I need it).

I’m trying to modify code I don’t understand in a language I haven’t learned, but I’ll settle for learning how to write an appropriate ring buffer.

Let me know if I should post code for this, but I’m not sure anything I could include would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pydub

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file("C:/Users/path_to/myAudio.wav" , "wav") 
chunk_length_ms = 2000 # pydub calculates in millisec
chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms) #Make chunks of two sec

#Export all of the individual chunks as wav files
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_name = "chunk{0}.wav".format(i)
    print ("exporting", chunk_name)
    chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")


#################output#########################

exporting chunk0.wav
exporting chunk1.wav
exporting chunk2.wav
exporting chunk3.wav
exporting chunk4.wav
exporting chunk5.wav
exporting chunk6.wav
exporting chunk7.wav
exporting chunk8.wav
exporting chunk9.wav
exporting chunk10.wav
exporting chunk11.wav
exporting chunk12.wav
exporting chunk13.wav
exporting chunk14.wav
exporting chunk15.wav
exporting chunk16.wav
exporting chunk17.wav
exporting chunk18.wav
exporting chunk19.wav
```

chunk.export method exports playable audio chunks to files (.wav here) that can be used for audio processing.Above chunks (chunk0.wav ... through .. chunk8.wav) are saved in the same folder that you run above scripts from. Use the last 2 seconds for callback function

Comment: I’ll try it. Thanks.

Comment: But how do I feed them into my callback function?